# How to append a value to a cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

It must have been 15 years since I set a cookie value with javascript ...

```
document.cookie = 'key=value';  //got that ...
```

How do I append another value with the same key? I want to create a list of values (page=1,34,48,59...) that I can then read and loop over. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to rewrite the cookie with the appended value. You can use delimiters to separate the values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify them all once eg:

```
var value = ['1', '2', '3', 'n'].join(',');
document.cookie = 'key=' + value;
```

where `'key=' + value` will now be:

```
key=1,2,3,n
```

Or alternatively, read your data from cookie first and add new data:

```
var keycookie = // read your cookie here
keycookie += 'new stuff';
document.cookie = 'key=' + keycookie;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `call` instead of `['1', '2', '3', 'n'].join(',')`?

Comment: @MattGreer: It's been my habit, updated with what you posed as it looks clean and terse.

Comment: so to append a value of 3 to my cookie "key" that already has a value of "1,2" I have to read the complete cookie, loop over it to extract the values for "key", add "3" and then write "key" again? There is no shortcut to append a value to an existing key?

Answer (score 1):

```
// name is cookie name
// value is cookie value
// days is life time of it
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * parseInt(days)));

parts = $.cookie(name);
if (!parts || parts == 'undefined') {
    $.cookie(name, value, {path: '/', expires: date });
    return;
}

parts = parts.split(",");
if (parts.length > 0) {
    // search same item and delete
    // if already have , delete it
    for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
        if (value == parts[i]) {
            parts.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    parts.push(value);

    // if over 50, just do 50
    newparts = [];
    if (parts.length > 50) {
        for (var i=parts.length - 50; i<parts.length; i++) {
            newparts.push(parts[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        newparts = parts;
    }
    $.cookie(name, newparts.join(","), {path: '/', expires: date });
}
else {
    $.cookie(name, $(this).attr("id"), {path: '/', expires: date });
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
function addToCart(value) {
    document.cookie = document.cookie+','+value;
    console.log(document.cookie);
    return;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Especialyl the unusual syntax, which gives an impression of being a failure to use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help